# i scraped title and price and links and info table and when i write csv file i get duplicated title and price and links

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to replace duplicate title and price and links with empty column values.

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://shop.kvgems-preciousstones.com/'

while True:
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"}

    content = session.get(url, verify=False).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    posts = soup.find_all('li',{'class':'item'})

    data = []
    for url in posts:

        title = url.find('h2',{'product-name'}).text
        price = url.find('span',{'price'}).text
        link = url.find('a').get('href')
        url_response = requests.get(link)
        url_data = url_response.text
        url_soup = BeautifulSoup(url_data, 'html.parser')

        desciption = url_soup.find('tr')
        for tr in url_soup.find_all('tr'):
            planet_data = dict()
            values = [td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')]
            planet_data['name'] = tr.find('td').text.strip()
            planet_data['info'] = tr.find_all('td')[1].text.strip()
            data.append((title,price,planet_data,link))   

    #data_new = data +","+ data_desciption
    #urls = soup.find('a',{'class': 'next i-next'}).get('href')
    #url = urls
    #print(url)

    with open('ineryrge5szdqzrt.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
     writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
     writer.writerow(['title','price','name','info','link'])
     #The for loop
     for title,price,planet_data,link in data:

     writer.writerow([title,price,planet_data['name'],planet_data['info'],link])
```

When I write CSV I got the result of duplicated title,  price,  link but I want to get only 1 title, price, info and link while the rest are empty.

Answer (score 0):

The first `for` loop extracts the common values (title, price and link). The second `for` loop then extracts all the data attributes for each item.

However, you are then writing title, price and link fields to the CSV file for **every row** of data. You only need to do it for the **first row** of data.

To detect if your second `for` loop is on the first row or not, you can change it to use the `enumerate` function which gives you an extra `index` variable. You can then use this value to only write the title, price, link if 0:

```
        for index, tr in enumerate(url_soup.find_all('tr')):
            planet_data = dict()
            values = [td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')]
            planet_data['name'] = tr.find('td').text.strip()
            planet_data['info'] = tr.find_all('td')[1].text.strip()
            if index == 0:
                data.append((title,price,planet_data,link))
            else:
                data.append((None,None,planet_data,None))
```

(Also I don't think you need the initial `while True:` part.)

Comment: Thank you for the solution . I have anthore problem and here is link of problem :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57073595/i-scraped-title-and-price-and-links-and-info-table-i-name-it-planet-data-and-whe